# AppData\Roaming\npm\nest.ps1 is not digitally signed

Tags: nestjs, executionpolicy

I am new to nestjs.
cloned a repo from github and it is written using nestjs.
(I wrote it with a friend (first time for both of us), so maybe there is a problem with that end...)
I try to install nest by running the command:

> npm install -g @nestjs/cli

It works, when I check the version I see 10.1.18, It's clearly installed.
But, when I try to run the cloned repo by typing

> nest start
> I get this error:

```
nest : File C:\Users\My-User\AppData\Roaming\npm\nest.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
C:\Users\ My-User \AppData\Roaming\npm\nest.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run
this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting
execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ nest start
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I tried changing the execution policy as shown by Microsoft, not working...
anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is uninstall the global nest,
then tried to install it in the folder.
it errored because of one of the packages I'm trying to use (bcrypt)
so I uninstalled that package, then installed nest, and it works.
Now I have to see how to install the bcrypt - but this is a different issue.